# sudo apt upgrade fails after "dpkg-statoverride: warning: no override present"

Tags: 18.04, apt, upgrade, dpkg, do-release-upgrade

I recently updated from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 using the terminal (`do-upgrade-release`). After the installation is complete, when I try `sudo apt upgrade`, I get the following warnings which eventually result in errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
11 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/15.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 326 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 351403 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic_4.15.0-29.31_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic (4.15.0-29.31) over (4.15.0-29.31~16.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/statoverride:
dpkg-statoverride: warning: no override present
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/statoverride exited with return code 2
dpkg: warning: old linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/statoverride:
dpkg-statoverride: warning: no override present
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/statoverride exited with return code 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic_4.15.0-29.31_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/statoverride:
dpkg-statoverride: warning: no override present
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/statoverride exited with return code 2
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 new linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic_4.15.0-45.48_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic (4.15.0-45.48) over (4.15.0-45.48~16.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/statoverride:
dpkg-statoverride: warning: no override present
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/statoverride exited with return code 2
dpkg: warning: old linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/statoverride:
dpkg-statoverride: warning: no override present
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/statoverride exited with return code 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic_4.15.0-45.48_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/statoverride:
dpkg-statoverride: warning: no override present
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/statoverride exited with return code 2
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 new linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic_4.15.0-29.31_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic_4.15.0-45.48_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It appears the issue is related to older linux kernels. I see the "16.04" in there as well, but I'm not sure how to interpret or fix this. `uname -r` returns:

```
4.15.0-88-generic
```

Comment: For me this happened after an upgrade session that got me from 10.04 to 20.04 through all intermediate LTS releases on one machine. `munin-node` refuses to be removed and remains in this half-something state ... I think in my case the _cause_ was that I removed the user created by that package. I was able to resolve it by installing the package and then later purging it successfully (`apt install --fix-missing --fix-broken --reinstall munin-node; apt autopurge munin-node`).